# Python construct a URL with username and password credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I'm trying to port some basic code from JavaScript to Python. In JavaScript the URL class makes this trivial:

```
const url = new URL('https://python.org');
url.username = 'foo';
url.password = 'bar';
    
console.log(url.href)
```

> https://foo:bar@python.org/

How do I do this *natively* in Python? In other words, how can this be done using core libraries (without any third party libraries e.g. the `requests` module)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try using f-strings like this:

```py
url = f"https://{username}:{password}@python.org"
print(url)
```

For instance, I use this technique to configure my applications to be able to access Internet when I am behing a corporate proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; string interpolation like this won't properly URLEncode or escape these values. That's why it's important to use something that follows the URL Standard: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/